# GraphQL: Are cursors part of a read transaction? Polling for new data

Tags: graphql, github-api

I am using GraphQL to download the entire dataset from an API.

Pagination is implemented using the `first` and `after` arguments.

If I order the items by create date desc, and my code is polling using the `after` set to the last item it received, will it see new items as they are created?

Or is the `cursor` like an actual database cursor where you are iterating over a result (inside an RDMS read transaction, which is like a snapshot of the result set)?

Note: The API does not implement `subscription` so I cannot subscribe to events.